# Netlogo - Flocking to others in agentset (as opposed to all turtles)

Tags: netlogo

Sorry, there probably is a simple answer to this problem, but I am relatively new to Netlogo and have spent a couple of days working on this to no avail, so any suggestions are really welcomed -thanks.

**There is a great flocking method** for flocking fish and birds (see MacLennan, 2007 (http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mclennan/Classes/420-594-F07/NetLogo/Flock.html)  based on the Huth and Wissel (1992)) and **I would like to adapt this flocking method, so that rather than flocking to your nearest three neighbours (who are all one homogeneous population), you only flock to those within your agentset,** or more specifically, those in your own group (ignoring those outside of it).

I understand that one suggestion may be to create two different breeds at the beginning, e.g. deer and moose, and then you only flock to those who belong to the same breed. However, in my example, **I have agents who reassess at each tick which group is most optimal to belong to, and flip between groups** (which are defined through agentsets).

The original code (MacLennan, 2007), for a homogeneous population is as follows:

```
TO GO ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set i 0                                            ; initializes variables used in finding neighbors
set distance_1 1000
set distance_2 1000
set distance_3 1000

   ; (below) determines ID numbers and distances for three closest neighbors; each turtle is
   ;   first checked to be visible (i.e., out of blind spot and in front of obstacles), and then
   ;   its distance is compared with that of neighbor_3.  If a bird is closer than neighbor_3,
   ;   it is then compared with neighbor_2 and (if it's closer than neighbor_2) with neighbor_1;
   ;   variables are then re-assigned to accomodate the new neighbor as one of the closest three.

repeat count turtles
  [ifelse not ((i = who) or in_blind_spot? or behind_opaque_obstacle?)
     [set dist distance turtle i
      ifelse dist < distance_3
        [ifelse dist < distance_2
           [set neighbor_3 neighbor_2
            set distance_3 distance_2
            ifelse dist < distance_1
              [set neighbor_2 neighbor_1
               set distance_2 distance_1
               set neighbor_1 i
               set distance_1 dist]               
              [set neighbor_2 i
               set distance_2 dist
               repeat 2 [fd 0]]]                 ; (see note at end for explanantion of "fd 0")
           [set neighbor_3 i
            set distance_3 dist
            repeat 4 [fd 0]]]
        [repeat 6 [fd 0]]]
     [repeat 7 [fd 0]]
   set i i + 1]

set acceleration 0                                ; sets acceleration to zero

set target_1 calc_target neighbor_1 distance_1    ; calculates targets (see procedure below) based on
set target_2 calc_target neighbor_2 distance_2    ;   the headings and positions of each neighbor;
set target_3 calc_target neighbor_3 distance_3    ;   acceleration is set by the calc_target procedure

   ; (below) calculates a bird's composite target, weighting each individual target by the inverse
   ;   of distance to that neighbor

set target atan ((sin target_1) * 100 / distance_1 + (sin target_2) * 100 / distance_2 + (sin target_3) * 100 / distance_3)
                ((cos target_1) * 100 / distance_1 + (cos target_2) * 100 / distance_2 + (cos target_3) * 100 / distance_3)

   ; (below) turns bird towards target by a fraction specified by "flexibility"; random motion is also
   ;   included to an extent governed by "noise".  The "... + 540) mod 360) - 180" clause is necessary to
   ;   ensure that the bird turns in the right direction.  For example, if a bird is oriented at 0 degrees
   ;   and its target is 300 degrees, it should consider a 60 [ = ((0 - 300 + 540) mod 360) - 180] degree
   ;   turn to the left instead of a 300 [ = 300 - 0] degree turn to the right.

fd 1 + acceleration                               ; moves birds forward

end
```

**I thought the easiest way to do this** would be to keep as much of the original code as possible and then look to **change the line of code**

```
[set dist distance turtle i
```

as turtle means any turtle in the world rather than only those turtles within my group.

To do this, **I thought about converting my agentset 'group-members' temporarily into a breed** so that I could replace the word turtle i with groupmember i.. e.g.

```
create-groupies-from group-members
[set dist distance group-member i
```

However, I when I tried to used the `create-<breed>-from` code I received an **error** that **'Nothing named CREATE-GROUPIES-FROM has been defined**, even when this breed was or was not included in breeds [ ]

**Therefore, I tried to adapt the code to only consider** flocking towards other **group members** as follows:

```
   to flock
set id-within-group 0                                            ; initializes variables used in finding neighbors
set distance_1 1000
set distance_2 1000
set distance_3 1000

set group-members turtle-set turtles with [group-id = [group-id] of myself] ; set those sharing a group id as my group-members
 (foreach (sort group-members) (n-values count group-members [?]) [ ; set each turtle in my agentset (group) with an ID no. 0 - n?
    ask ?1 [ set id-within-group ?2 ]
  ])
repeat count group-members ; repeat the next step as many times as there are group members
  [ifelse not (id-within-group = who)
     [
       set dist distance turtle id-within-group
       print "turtle id-within-group"
       print turtle id-within-group
       print dist
      ifelse dist < distance_3
        [ifelse dist < distance_2
           [set neighbor_3 neighbor_2
            set distance_3 distance_2
            ifelse dist < distance_1
              [set neighbor_2 neighbor_1
               set distance_2 distance_1
               set neighbor_1 id-within-group
               set distance_1 dist]               
              [set neighbor_2 id-within-group
               set distance_2 dist
               repeat 2 [fd 0]]]                 
           [set neighbor_3 id-within-group
            set distance_3 dist
            repeat 4 [fd 0]]]
        [repeat 6 [fd 0]]]
     [repeat 7 [fd 0]]
   print "_____________________"
   print "ID" print self
   print "group-id" print group-id
   ]

;]
set acceleration 0                                ; sets acceleration to zero

set target_1 calc_target neighbor_1 distance_1    ; calculates targets (see procedure below) based on
set target_2 calc_target neighbor_2 distance_2    ;   the headings and positions of each neighbor;
set target_3 calc_target neighbor_3 distance_3    ;   acceleration is set by the calc_target procedure


   ; (below) calculates a bird's composite target, weighting each individual target by the inverse
   ;   of distance to that neighbor

set target atan ((sin target_1) * 100 / distance_1 + (sin target_2) * 100 / distance_2 + (sin target_3) * 100 / distance_3)
                ((cos target_1) * 100 / distance_1 + (cos target_2) * 100 / distance_2 + (cos target_3) * 100 / distance_3)

   ; (below) turns bird towards target by a fraction specified by "flexibility"; random motion is also
   ;   included to an extent governed by "noise".  The "... + 540) mod 360) - 180" clause is necessary to
   ;   ensure that the bird turns in the right direction.  For example, if a bird is oriented at 0 degrees
   ;   and its target is 300 degrees, it should consider a 60 [ = ((0 - 300 + 540) mod 360) - 180] degree
   ;   turn to the left instead of a 300 [ = 300 - 0] degree turn to the right.

lt (flexibility / 100 * (((heading - target + 540) mod 360) - 180)) + (random noise) - (random noise)

fd 1 + acceleration                               ; moves birds forward

end
```

In my modified example, while the groups do correctly assign an individual ID group members, they do not flock towards their own. Also the neighbor,distance and target_1 - _3 all have the same values which is wrong.

I was wondering if anyone has any insight into some of the problems I am having? Any solutions or relevant literature would be really appreciated - **Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

First, just to let you know, turtles can change breeds simply by asking the relevant turtle to set its breed property to the new breed: `ask ... [set breed ...]` (see breed primitive in the NetLogo dictionary for an example).

Nevertheless, I think you are correct to do this with a 'group' property and use agentsets to do what you want. This is something like what you want but not correct. Hopefully someone else will be able to improve it.

```
turtles-own
[ groupID ]

to setup

  create-turtles 20
  [ set groupID random 2
    set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
  ]

  ask turtles
  [ let close-friends min-n-of 3 turtles with [groupID = [groupID] of myself] [distance myself]
    ask close-friends
    [ face myself
      forward 1
    ]
  ]

end
```

This code (I think) finds the three closest turtles in the same group. However, it moves those three towards the asking turtle rather than moving the asking turtle to move towards those three. I can't work out how to do the other way around without doing ugly stuff with lists.

Comment: Hi JenB. Thank you very much for your reply - unforunately as you rightly state yourself, your suggestion does not help me solve my problem at the moment. But nonetheless, thank you very much for your reply. I am still desperately seeking a solution to this problem. I absolutely love the MacLennan, 2007 flocking method, and my overall goal is to stay as faithful to this code as possible, whilst flocking towards those in my agentset - so if anyone else has any suggestions please let me know, but thank you JenB.

Answer (score 0):

okay, here's a corrected version (i didn't edit the above because that would mess up the comments). There's still no error checking to make sure there are 3 others in the group etc, but this uses lists to get round the problem in the first suggestion. It creates the agentset close-friends to contain the three closest (which is a single line instead of all the nested distance checking). That agentset is converted to a list and then the code loops through the list and moves towards the list member. I still think there must be a better way of looping directly through the agentset, but at least this works.

```
turtles-own
[ groupID ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20
  [ set groupID random 2
    set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
    set color 155 - 10 * groupID
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ let close-friends min-n-of 3 turtles with [groupID = [groupID] of myself] [distance myself]
    let friend-list sort-on [distance myself] close-friends
    foreach friend-list
    [ face ?
      forward 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting back to me, however the problem is somewhat different. Instead of grouping the agents together in little clusters (as in your suggested method), I would really like my groups of agents (agentsets) to align, cohere and seperate - similar to a group of flocking birds (the MacLennan model I cited above). The only alteration to the MacLennan flocking method that I would like to make would be to consider one's own agentset when calculating flocking headings/distances rather than considering all turtles (regardless of group membership). I hope this makes sense and thanks again

Comment: To get the flocking behaviour in the MacLennan model, you need to do the calculation of how to move in the same way - all that content about acceleration and distancing. That has nothing to do with selecting closest 3 from same group rather than closest 3 overall so I didn't include it in the example code, I just made them move so you could see that it works.